# Collapsing Toolbar Layout using same toolbar on differents fragments depending on behaviour

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-appcompat, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I've trying to update my app by giving some Material Design behaviour. Until now my app have a navigation drawer and a MainActivity that loads the desire fragment based on the item click in the drawer menu (as follows:)

[image]

When you click in "Consejos" it replace the fragment with the desire content as follows

MainActivity

```
private void selectItem(String title, int id) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(PlaceholderFragment.ARG_SECTION_TITLE, title);

        Fragment fragment = PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(title);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_content, fragment)
                .commit();


        switch (id) {
            case R.id.nav_localizacion:
                //Snackbar.make(mSnackBarView, R.string.menu_localization, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
                LocalizacionFragment fragment_localizacion = new LocalizacionFragment();
//                fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
//                Snackbar.make(mSnackBarView, R.string.menu_localization, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                fragmentManager
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.main_content, fragment_localizacion)
                        .commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_productos:
                Snackbar.make(mSnackBarView, R.string.menu_productos, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mCurrentSelectedPosition = 1;
                fragmentManager
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.main_content, fragment)
                        .commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_consejos:
                Snackbar.make(mSnackBarView, R.string.menu_consejos, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mCurrentSelectedPosition = 3;
                ConsejosFragment fragment_consejo = new ConsejosFragment();
//                final Fragment fragment_consejo = new ConsejosFragment();
                fragmentManager
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.main_content, fragment_consejo)
                        .commit();
//                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_content, fragment_consejo).commit();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }


        drawerLayout.closeDrawers(); // Cerrar drawer

        setTitle(title); // título actual

    }
```

It opens this:

[image]

Then, if you click on "Recetas" again replaces the fragment with the desire content:

[image]

But here is the thing, if you click on a item I want to open another fragment and use the AppBarLayout along with CollapsingToolbarLayout to show an image with the recipe.

This is the layout of the recipe content description:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content_recetas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/redono_ternera_mechado"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="24dp">

            <include layout="@layout/card_layout" />

            <include layout="@layout/card_layout" />

            <include layout="@layout/card_layout" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is the code of the RecipeDescription Fragment

```
public class RecetaViewFragment extends Fragment {

    private Context context;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /* Inflamos el layout */
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recetas_descripcion_layout, container, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.backdrop);
        Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.sopa_goulash_ternera).into(imageView);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) v.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_view);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            toolbar.setSubtitle("Descripción");
        }
        context = v.getContext();
        return v;
    }
```

But this is what happend when running the app:

[image]

[image]

It has the collapse toolbar embedded in the original toolbar, my question is if my approach isn't the right approach. I mean, I have to only have one toolbar and then applied or not the collapsing behaviour whether I need it or not, or I have to find a way for hiding the original toolbar and using this one (but what happens when I want to give proper back navigation to my app?)

Thank you, please ask me for more code if need it

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am having a similar problem.

MY CASE:

I want a Toolbar in the Activity, since I have a Navigation Drawer, but also want to use the Collapsing Toolbar in Fragment.

I just did one change which I am happy with.

In the Fragment Toolbar I added this:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```